# Conditional text in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, code-behind

How do I conditionally render a particular text in Xamarin Forms 5?

For example, I get some data from my API backend for a vendor and there may be an address in the database for this vendor or not.

If I do have vendor's address, I'd like to display it and if I don't have an address, I'd like to display something like "n/a".

Is there a way to handle this in the XAML page or do I have to handle it in code behind?

UPDATE:
Here's what the XAML page for the phone numbers `ListView` looks like:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" RowDefinitions="150, *" ColumnDefinitions="250, 250">
   <StackLayout
      Grid.Row="0"
      Grid.Column="0"
      Padding="10">
      <ListView
         BackgroundColor="Transparent"
         SeparatorVisibility="None"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Contact.PhoneNumbers, TargetNullValue='n/a'}">
         <ListView.Header>
            <StackLayout>
               <Label Text="Phone Number(s)"
                  FontAttributes="Bold"/>
            </StackLayout>
         </ListView.Header>
         <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextCell Text="{Binding PhoneNumberDisplay}" />
            </DataTemplate>
         </ListView.ItemTemplate>
      </ListView>
   </StackLayout>
</Grid>
```

Comment: the FallbackValue property allows a fallback value to be defined that will be used when the binding source can't be resolved

Comment: In his case TargetNullValue is more appropriate check link in my answer, it will fall over the predefined value when the bound property is null

Comment: yes, I think you are right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use xaml binding with [TargetNullValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/binding-fallbacks#defining-a-null-replacement-value)

```
<Label Text="{Binding Location, TargetNullValue='n/a'}"/>
```

If you don't have an address your API or your code should set `Location` to null in order for TargetNullValue to work.

**Update** (reply to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71390053/conditional-text-in-xamarin-forms/71391126?noredirect=1#comment126201193_71391126)).

Use `TargetNullValue` in the bindings inside ItemTemplate (applies to each single element) and not on itemsource binding:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" RowDefinitions="150, *" ColumnDefinitions="250, 250">
   <StackLayout
      Grid.Row="0"
      Grid.Column="0"
      Padding="10">
      <ListView
         BackgroundColor="Transparent"
         SeparatorVisibility="None"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Contact.PhoneNumbers}">
         <ListView.Header>
            <StackLayout>
               <Label Text="Phone Number(s)"
                  FontAttributes="Bold"/>
            </StackLayout>
         </ListView.Header>
         <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextCell Text="{Binding PhoneNumberDisplay, TargetNullValue='n/a'}" />
            </DataTemplate>
         </ListView.ItemTemplate>
      </ListView>
   </StackLayout>
</Grid>
```

Comment: One follow up question: I use `TargetNullValue` in a `ListView` and if there's no value, it shows n/a but vertically. So, `n` in line 1, `/` in line 2 and `a` in line 3 which looks weird. Any idea how to make it look like an item if the list had any data in it?

Comment: I have to first reproduce the issue you described, mind sharing a minimal xaml sample to reproduce?

Comment: Just added a section of the `XAML` code in the original post under "UPDATE".